# При сохранении статьи возникает ошибка:

Tags: laravel

Когда нажимаю кнопку "сохранить", получаю такую ошибку:

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException 
No message
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php

[image: скорее всего ошибка в виде]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка которая видна на рисунке возникали по причине неправильного роута:

```
<h2>Создание нового продукта</h2>
<form action="/admin/createProduct" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Решено:  всегда смотрим какой роут ожидаем:

В моём случае,  конечно не createProduct
Значит меняем в форме на правильный: storageProduct

```
<h2>Создание нового продукта</h2>
<form action="/admin/storeProduct" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```